# Bottom margin effect on centered items in horizontal snapped recyclerview

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I have an horizontal recycler view snapping to center position. I want to set a bottom margin to centered items gradually. It's like os x dock grow effect, but i don't want to scale up, i want to push up.

[image]

I've done it with animations but it's not a good result and they are fired on recycler view scroll state changes.

Someone can indicate a solution to me?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a lot of time I'm here to share my solution, more simple than I believed. I have extended RecyclerView and overriden onDraw method to set margin to RecyclerView's children based on their distance from center. It's not much clear, but now I have no time to make it better, and if someone need it, he can take a look to take inspiration

```
@Override
public void onDraw(Canvas c) {
    super.onDraw(c);

    int size = getChildCount();
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
       View v = getChildAt(i);
       int x = DisplayHelper.pxToDp(act, (int) v.getX());
       topMargin = x - startXCenter;
       if (topMargin < -100 || topMargin > 100) {
           topMargin = MAX_MARGIN;
       } else if (topMargin < 0) {
          topMargin *= -1;
       }
       topMargin = topMargin - MAX_MARGIN;
       if (null != v) {
          v.setY(topMargin);
       }
    }
}
```